# How to tell Ubuntu not to check link to directory?

Tags: 14.04

I have created a link to some directory on a partition that will not be automaticaly mounted at start-up. Of course, when I restart the computer Ubuntu marks this link as "Broken". Is there a way to tell Ubuntu 14.04 not to check this link's path until I click on the link.

Edit: Is there a way to make Ubuntu recheck the link with some command?

Comment: The link is re-checked every time you refers to it, in a ls, cd or other command, or click at it in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way to make broken link work again. Instead of rechecking the link it is easier to remake the link. (Yes I know..LOL..I have little experience in Linux). When the partition is mounted I have done this in Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) writing the command:

`ln -s -f "path_to_Target" "path_to_Link/LINK_NAME"`

`ln` command is used to make soft or hard links.
The `-s` option is to make "soft link" and the `-f` option is to "force" making it so that it does not give me an error because the link already exists. The `ln` command is described in more detail [here.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ln.1.html)

Next stage is to make the link run the command by itself when clicked. I posted another question for this.

Comment: Instead of re-making the link each and every time, just make the file system mount at boot. There's no point in having link to something that doesn't exist (as far as OS is concerned). I've exactly same situation - I've got symlink to folder on secondary hard-drive. It mounts at boot as defined in `/etc/fstab`, and never had issue with symlink

Comment: It's difficult to mount a removable disk that doesn't exist in the room at the time of boot though. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could always bind mount the directory to a location that always exists and then link to that location.

So for instance, say you have `/dev/sdb1` mounted on `/media/user/sdb1`. This contains the directory `ClientDocs`, which you want to have a link to on your desktop at all times.

You could then add the directory `/media/permadirs/user/ClientDocs`. Then, when you have your disk mounted, you can do `sudo mount --bind /media/user/sdb1/ClientDocs /media/permadirs/user/ClientDocs`.

You can then make a link to `/media/permadirs/user/ClientDocs` and this link will always be valid, whether or not the disk is mounted.

You'll still need to do the mounting, of course, but the link will always work. Perhaps that helps you in some way.